# How to randomly generate pair of people using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have list of people and I want to pair them without any repeats of their names.

Here is my code:

```
var people = ['John', 'Jane', 'Harry', 'Mark', 'Steph', 'Mae']
var generatedPairs = [];
var arr1 = people.slice(),
    arr2 = people.slice();
arr1.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random();});
arr2.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random();});

while (arr1.length) {
  let pair = [];
  var name1 = arr1.pop();
  var name2 = arr2[0] == name1 ? arr2.pop() : arr2.shift();
  pair.push({from: name1, to: name2});
  generatedPairs.push(pair);
}

for(let i in generatedPairs) {
    console.log(generatedPairs[i][0].from+' - '+generatedPairs[i][0].to)
}
console.log("=================");
```

Sample Result:

```
Mae - Jane
Jane - Harry
Steph - Mae
John - Steph
Mark - John
Harry - Mark
=================
```

That code is working fine because it has even number of people which is 6.

But if, there are odd number of people (sample 5), there might be a possibility that the name of 1 person will repeat

```
var people = ['John', 'Jane', 'Harry', 'Mark', 'Steph']
var generatedPairs = [];
var arr1 = people.slice(),
    arr2 = people.slice();
arr1.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random();});
arr2.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random();});

while (arr1.length) {
  let pair = [];
  var name1 = arr1.pop();
  var name2 = arr2[0] == name1 ? arr2.pop() : arr2.shift();
  pair.push({from: name1, to: name2});
  generatedPairs.push(pair);
}

for(let i in generatedPairs) {
    console.log(generatedPairs[i][0].from+' - '+generatedPairs[i][0].to)
}
console.log("=================");
```

Sometimes the result will be like this.

```
Steph - Jane
Jane - John
John - Mark
Mark - Steph
Harry - Harry   <-- this one repeat its name
=================
```

How can I handle that situation which has odd number of people?
I'm using javascript for this one. Hope you can help me to solve this problem. thanks.

Here is my fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/g7xsdnbp/9/

Comment: And, what you want to do in that case? Would be allowed that _Harry_ be matched with _Jane_ when _Jane_ was already matched with _Steph_. If not, then would be allowed to amit _Harry_ at all?

Comment: Nope, there might be a possible result such as like this (Steph - Harry)
(Mark - John),
(Harry - Jane),
(John - Mark),
(Jane - Steph)
They are 5 people (odd number) but then, none of them repeat there names and that's the thing I want to achieve

Comment: So, the names can't repeat ***within*** a pair? Or, they can't repeat in position 1 of any pair? Or in position 2 in any pair? Please clarify.

Comment: name can't repeat it self in a pair and can't repeat in position 1 and 2 in any pair

Comment: just like in a normal pair. you know. Does it make sense?

Comment: Will something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/a4nxyt87/) work?

Comment: Yes. Something like that

Answer (score 0):

If we loop while the length of the array is greater than equal 2, it will stop when we no longer have enough to make a pair regardless of the length of the array being odd or even.

I would simply use splice to remove the element from the array to avoid reusing elements.  I also wouldn't use 2 different arrays unless there was a compelling reason to store 2 copies in memory.

I have a working example below:

```js
    let people = ['John', 'Jane', 'Harry', 'Mark', 'Steph', 'Mae', 'Justin']
    let set = new Set();

    while (people.length >= 2){
     let r1 = Math.random() * people.length;
        let person1 = people.splice(r1, 1)[0];
  
        let r2 = Math.random() * people.length;
        let person2 = people.splice(r2, 1)[0];
  
        set.add({from: person1, to: person2});
        console.log("from: " + person1 + " to: " + person2);
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Hans. Please don't link to 3rd party sites to show your working code as those links can die over time. Just insert a "code snippet" (from the toolbar you see when composing an answer) into your answer, right here as I've done for you.

Comment: Umm. You've to generate 7 pair-matches for 7 people. You generated 3 for 7. Look at the example in the question.

Comment: Ah, wasn't clear at the time of the post.  It sounded as if names could not repeat in any position of the pair.

Comment: No issue. Keep trying. :)

Comment: Something like in secret santa pair. You guys know that?

Answer (score 0):

Here a possible solution:

- The number of possible different pairs (not considering the order) and different names is given by `((people.length - 1) * people.length)/2`. 'John -  Jane' and 'Jane - John' is counted as one.
- We could get all unique combinations (not considering the order here) using a nested `for loop`, but the the second loop with `j = i+1` to not repeat the same person.
- Then we choose a random pair and we decide the order of the couple using a random [reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).  Then we [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the array to not choose the same pair.
- As a result we get all possible pairs combinations in random order.

```js
let people = ['John', 'Jane', 'Harry', 'Mark', 'Steph']

var pairs = [];

for(let i = 0; i<people.length; i++){
    for(let j = i+1; j<people.length; j++){
    pairs.push([people[i], people[j]])
    }    
}

while(pairs.length){
    let pair = Math.floor(Math.random() * pairs.length)
    let temp = pairs.splice(pair,1);
    if(Math.floor(Math.random()*2)) temp[0].reverse()//<-- pair order
    console.log(temp[0].join(" - "))
}
```